# Python AttributeError: 'figure()' is not a Qt property or a signal

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, pycharm, anaconda

Below is a simple code I am trying to run:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

movies=["Annie", "Ben","Casa", "Gandhi", "West"]
num_oscars=[5,11,3,8,10]

xs=[i+0.1 for i, _ in enumerate(movies)]

plt.bar(xs,num_oscars)
```

I got the following error (run in pycharm, Anaconda installed, python 2.7):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AlexPower/Desktop/python/myCode/ch2_new_1", line 15, in <module>
    plt.bar(xs,num_oscars)
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2692, in bar
    ax = gca()
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 950, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 586, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 44, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, thisFig)
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 51, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 242, in __init__
    super(FigureCanvasQTAgg, self).__init__(figure=figure)
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 66, in __init__
    super(FigureCanvasQTAggBase, self).__init__(figure=figure)
  File "C:\Users\AlexPower\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 243, in __init__
    super(FigureCanvasQT, self).__init__(figure=figure) 


AttributeError: 'figure()' is not a Qt property or a signal
```

I searched online and did sth like

```
import os

    if 'QT_API' not in os.environ and 'ETS_TOOLKIT' not in os.environ: 
        os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'
        os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4
```

It did not help.

kindly advise.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

`PySide2` and `PySide6` both ***do not*** yet properly support cooperative multiple inheritance:

- See [PYSIDE-1564](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1564)

There are many different bugs stemming from this documented in the [Qt for Python Development Notes 2021](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Development_Notes_2021)

Secondly, `PyQt` and `PySide` only accept keyword arguments for optional arguments (i.e. those that are specified as having default values in the docs). See the [PyQt4 docs](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/PyQt/keyword_arguments.html) and [PYSIDE-1964](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1964).

Therefore, `figure` is getting passed to the `QWidget` as a keyword argument, which creates the error that gets output by [pyside.cpp::fillQtProperties](https://github.com/pyside/pyside-setup/blob/69d43ea814788a18e8d77920d493fd84f6fc699a/sources/pyside6/libpyside/pyside.cpp#L129).

To work around this, `matplotlib` currently [does the following](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/0371cf971ff5c81a963683e3e1c2d48002929e21/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py#L173):

```py
# To work around lack of cooperative inheritance in PySide2 and
# PySide6, when calling FigureCanvasQT.__init__, we temporarily patch
# QWidget.__init__ by a cooperative version, that first calls
# QWidget.__init__ with no additional arguments, and then finds the
# next class in the MRO with an __init__ that does support cooperative
# inheritance (i.e., not defined by the PyQt4 or sip, or PySide{,2,6}
# or Shiboken packages), and manually call its `__init__`, once again
# passing the additional arguments.
```

This method was recommended by Raymond Hettinger in his PyCon 2015 talk [Super considered super!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) and his corresponding [blog post](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: "Secondly, PyQt and PySide only accept keyword arguments for optional arguments": thanks, that helped me debug it!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem while running a Canopy environment. I saw the problem in the editor, but plotted correctly in iPython. Turns out the PyLab backend was misconfigured, and trying PyQT4. I changed it to Interactive (wx) and works fine now.

[image]